# problem executing javascript function on a php page

Tags: php, jquery, tabs

I have a php file as given below. The page generates html content which is actually made of 3 html pages. I am using jquery tabs to put the three html pages in to tabs. The tab generation takes place in a function "loadtabs" which is called inside script tags at the bottom of the page. The problem i face is that the function i use to generate tabs is not executing in the php .Kindly help me figure out the problem.

editor.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="../../css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
<link type="text/css" href="./methodeditor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
<script>



function loadtabs() {



          $( ".tabs" ).tabs();


          method = <? echo $method; ?>;
          mode = <? echo $mode; ?>;


          $("#oven").load('oven.php');
          $("#detectors").load('detectors.php');
          $("#inlets").load('inlets.php');

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="editor" action="method.php" method="POST" >
<div class="editor">

<div class="tabs">

    <ul>


        <li><a href="#oven">Oven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#detectors">Detectors</a></li>
        <li><a href="#inlets">Inlets</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="oven" ></div>
    <div id="detectors" ></div>
    <div id="inlets"> </div>

</div>
<script>
loadtabs();
</script>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors on the page? What are the values of $method and $mode? Why aren't they wrapped in strings - `"<?php echo $mode; ?>"`?

Comment: Thanks... not wrapping the php code as a string was the problem...

Comment: Cool, shame someone else nicked my answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ahve not specifed the quotes in the js. Try this

```
function loadtabs() {



          $( ".tabs" ).tabs();


          method = "<? echo $method; ?>";
          mode = "<? echo $mode; ?>";


          $("#oven").load('oven.php');
          $("#detectors").load('detectors.php');
          $("#inlets").load('inlets.php');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, there is a **.load** which is a shortcut to .bind('load', handler) and **.load** which is part of an Ajax module.  Which one is fired depends on the arguments.

Because you are providing an URL as an argument without a selector appended to it, it will NOT strip any JavaScript contained inside the document and will execute the JavaScript block(s) prior to being passed to .html()

Make sure the JavaScript, if any, inside those PHP files is free of errors.